# Where to Run Scripts at a PyCharm Debugger Breakpoint?

Tags: python, pycharm

When running the PyCharm debugger and having stopped at a break point, is there a console to run and display some computation with the local variable exposed to me?

What I have in mind is the debugger setup in Matlab, where when stopped at a break point in a function, one can run scripts using the variables inside the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood well what do you mean, yes, PyCharm provides you a console where you can run local scripts or just see the variable's value at breakpoint time.

Start PyCharm debugger and at the bottom of your window you should see the main console.

You have to press a botton named "Show Python Prompt". Now, you should be able to write in console.

Look at the picture for more details.

[image]

Comment: is it possible to run a selection of commands?  say if you have five lines in your code that you want to run, can you highlight them and right click them or something?  i notice that you can't copy and paste them into the python prompt; it just executes the first line if you do that.

Comment: I found it. Thank you. However, this "Show Python Prompt" button only show up after you have pressed "Console" button on the left of the second row from the top next to the "Debugger" button. That button will show in your image if the width of it is larger. It will be good if you add this piece of information and show a slightly larger image, because I could not find the panel containing the "Show Python Prompt" button as shown in your image initially.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Evaluate Expression`](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/adding-editing-and-removing-watches.html) and [`Watches`](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/adding-editing-and-removing-watches.html) features to run code while debugging.

Comment: Thank you. These are very useful.